# Move an object up while touch is active

Tags: 2d, unity, android, mobile

I'm trying to move an object towards the top of the screen while the touch is active.
This is my current code. When I am touching the screen, the object I'm trying to move just keeps it's place (and the gravity seems to be disabled from this point). I'd be glad if someone could help me in this case. Thanks in advance!

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{

public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 12);
public int speed = 3;

void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
                    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (i);
                    while(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                            // Touch are screens location. Convert to world
                                rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(0, speed);
                                rigidbody2D.AddForce(jumpForce);
                    } 

            }
     }
 }
```

Comment: The code you've postedis only checking for touches that *began* on this frame. If all you want is to verify that any touch is present, you can just check if `Input.touchCount` is greater than zero.

Comment: @rutter that's worthy of an answer. You should make one.

Comment: @Blue Done. I'm still getting used to this area of Stack Exchange, so wasn't sure about answering vs. commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted is only checking for touches that began on this frame. If all you want is to verify that any touch is present, you can just check if [`Input.touchCount`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html) is greater than zero.